step_ns() in tidymodels: Error in `step_ns()`: Caused by error in `qr.default()`: ! NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
I want to fit a linear model and I want to add splines of all numerical variables using tidyverse for evaluation, and ideally for penalization.
While this sounds clever, I cannot figure out how to make it work, as it produces a nonsense error message no matter what I try. There are no proper examples of this given anywhere I can find, and GPT4o doesn't know either.
This example works, but fails if one tries to add step_ns(all_predictors(), deg_free = 3) to the recipe as shown in the documentation and examples:
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

#choose a suitable build in dataset with numerical variables
bfi = psych::bfi %>% na.omit()
bfi %>% nrow()
#> [1] 2236

#minimal subset
bfi = bfi %>% select(A1:O5, age)

#with roles
bfi_rec = recipe(
  bfi,
  vars = bfi %>% select(age, A1:O5) %>% names(),
  roles = c("outcome", rep("predictor", 25)),
)

#with formula
# bfi_rec = recipe(
#   age ~ .,
#   data = bfi,
# ) 

#model
bfi_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

#workflow
bfi_wf = workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(bfi_rec) %>%
  add_model(bfi_model)

#cross validation
set.seed(1)
bfi_folds = vfold_cv(bfi, v = 5)

#resampling
bfi_res = fit_resamples(
  bfi_wf,
  bfi_folds,
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)

#results
bfi_res %>%
  collect_metrics() %>%
  filter(.metric == "rsq")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   .metric .estimator   mean     n std_err .config             
#>   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 rsq     standard   0.0730     5 0.00538 Preprocessor1_Model1

If one tries with step_ns(), the bug is caused when prep() is implicitly called:
#...

#with roles
bfi_rec = recipe(
  bfi,
  vars = bfi %>% select(age, A1:O5) %>% names(),
  roles = c("outcome", rep("predictor", 25)),
) %>% 
  step_ns(all_predictors(), deg_free = 3)

#...

#resampling
bfi_res = fit_resamples(
  bfi_wf,
  bfi_folds,
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)
#> → A | error:   Error in `step_ns()`:
#>                Caused by error in `qr.default()`:
#>                ! NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
#> There were issues with some computations   A: x1
#> There were issues with some computations   A: x5
#> 
#> Warning: All models failed. Run `show_notes(.Last.tune.result)` for more
#> information.

Things I've also tried:

Using formula age ~ . instead of roles, but I prefer roles because I have many variables.
Other datasets, the above is an example dataset not the one I work with.
Other engines, glmnet.
This was the only related question I could find, but it is an improper example.


The cause is the parameter to step_ns(). The deg_free = 3 does apparently not do as the documentation says, instead causing the misleading error that sounds like there's missing data (which we know there isn't). If one leaves it out, the code works:
#results
bfi_res %>%
  collect_metrics() %>%
  filter(.metric == "rsq")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   .metric .estimator   mean     n std_err .config             
#>   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 rsq     standard   0.0879     5  0.0101 Preprocessor1_Model1


I cannot reproduce the issue with the current CRAN versions (see below). This may have been fixed recently.
Also, we'll be deprecating step_ns() in favor of step_spline_natural() so you might want to switch
library(tidymodels)

#choose a suitable build in dataset with numerical variables
bfi = psych::bfi %>% na.omit()
bfi %>% nrow()
#> [1] 2236

#minimal subset
bfi = bfi %>% select(A1:O5, age)

#with roles
bfi_rec = recipe(
  bfi,
  vars = bfi %>% select(age, A1:O5) %>% names(),
  roles = c("outcome", rep("predictor", 25)),
)

#model
bfi_model = linear_reg() %>%
  set_engine("lm") %>%
  set_mode("regression")

#workflow
bfi_wf = workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(bfi_rec) %>%
  add_model(bfi_model)

#cross validation
set.seed(1)
bfi_folds = vfold_cv(bfi, v = 5)

#resampling
bfi_res = fit_resamples(
  bfi_wf,
  bfi_folds,
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)

#results
bfi_res %>%
  collect_metrics() %>%
  filter(.metric == "rsq")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   .metric .estimator   mean     n std_err .config             
#>   <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1 rsq     standard   0.0730     5 0.00538 Preprocessor1_Model1

#with roles
bfi_rec = recipe(
  bfi,
  vars = bfi %>% select(age, A1:O5) %>% names(),
  roles = c("outcome", rep("predictor", 25)),
) %>% 
  step_ns(all_predictors(), deg_free = 3)

#resampling
bfi_res = fit_resamples(
  bfi_wf,
  bfi_folds,
  control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE)
)
bfi_res
#> # Resampling results
#> # 5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>   splits             id    .metrics         .notes           .predictions      
#>   <list>             <chr> <list>           <list>           <list>            
#> 1 <split [1788/448]> Fold1 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [448 × 4]>
#> 2 <split [1789/447]> Fold2 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [447 × 4]>
#> 3 <split [1789/447]> Fold3 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [447 × 4]>
#> 4 <split [1789/447]> Fold4 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [447 × 4]>
#> 5 <split [1789/447]> Fold5 <tibble [2 × 4]> <tibble [0 × 3]> <tibble [447 × 4]>

Created on 2024-09-30 with reprex v2.1.0


Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
#>  os       macOS Sonoma 14.6.1
#>  system   aarch64, darwin20
#>  ui       X11
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       America/New_York
#>  date     2024-09-30
#>  pandoc   3.1.11 @ /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools/aarch64/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package      * version    date (UTC) lib source
#>  backports      1.5.0      2024-05-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  broom        * 1.0.6      2024-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  class          7.3-22     2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  cli            3.6.3      2024-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  codetools      0.2-20     2024-03-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  colorspace     2.1-1      2024-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  data.table     1.15.4     2024-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  dials        * 1.3.0      2024-07-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  DiceDesign     1.10       2023-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  digest         0.6.36     2024-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  dplyr        * 1.1.4      2023-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  evaluate       0.23       2023-11-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fansi          1.0.6      2023-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fastmap        1.2.0      2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  foreach        1.5.2      2022-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  fs             1.6.4      2024-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  furrr          0.3.1      2022-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  future         1.34.0     2024-07-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  future.apply   1.11.2     2024-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  generics       0.1.3      2022-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  ggplot2      * 3.5.1      2024-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  globals        0.16.3     2024-03-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  glue           1.7.0      2024-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  gower          1.0.1      2022-12-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  GPfit          1.0-8      2019-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  gtable         0.3.5      2024-04-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  hardhat        1.4.0      2024-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  htmltools      0.5.8.1    2024-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  infer        * 1.0.7      2024-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  ipred          0.9-15     2024-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  iterators      1.0.14     2022-02-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  knitr          1.46       2024-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lattice        0.22-6     2024-03-20 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  lava           1.8.0      2024-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lhs            1.2.0      2024-06-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lifecycle      1.0.4      2023-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  listenv        0.9.1      2024-01-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  lubridate      1.9.3      2023-09-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  magrittr       2.0.3      2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  MASS           7.3-61     2024-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  Matrix         1.7-0      2024-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  mnormt         2.1.1      2022-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  modeldata    * 1.4.0      2024-06-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  munsell        0.5.1      2024-04-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  nlme           3.1-165    2024-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  nnet           7.3-19     2023-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#>  parallelly     1.38.0     2024-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  parsnip      * 1.2.1      2024-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  pillar         1.9.0      2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  pkgconfig      2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  prodlim        2024.06.25 2024-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  psych          2.4.6.26   2024-06-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  purrr        * 1.0.2      2023-08-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.cache        0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.methodsS3    1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.oo           1.26.0     2024-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R.utils        2.12.3     2023-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  R6             2.5.1      2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  Rcpp           1.0.13     2024-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  recipes      * 1.1.0      2024-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  reprex         2.1.0      2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rlang          1.1.4      2024-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rmarkdown      2.27       2024-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rpart          4.1.23     2023-12-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rsample      * 1.2.1      2024-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  rstudioapi     0.16.0     2024-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  scales       * 1.3.0      2023-11-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  sessioninfo    1.2.2      2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  styler         1.10.3     2024-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  survival       3.7-0      2024-06-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tibble       * 3.2.1      2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidymodels   * 1.2.0      2024-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyr        * 1.3.1      2024-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tidyselect     1.2.1      2024-03-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  timechange     0.3.0      2024-01-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  timeDate       4032.109   2023-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  tune         * 1.2.1      2024-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  utf8           1.2.4      2023-10-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  vctrs          0.6.5      2023-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  withr          3.0.1      2024-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  workflows    * 1.1.4      2024-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  workflowsets * 1.1.0      2024-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  xfun           0.43       2024-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  yaml           2.3.8      2023-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#>  yardstick    * 1.3.1      2024-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#> 
#>  [1] /Users/max/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library
#>  [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library
#> 
#> ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

